# Whether to write in "ui.R + server.R" or "app.R"

Tags: r, shiny

We can write our Shiny code in two separate files, `"ui.R"` and `"server.R"`, alternatively we can write both the modules in a single file `"app.R"` and call the function `shinyApp()`

Is there any benefit regarding performance with either of the two approaches or we should choose one based on whether we want concise code or differentiated one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that `app.R` is better, but it's better to include your source files as the UI and server respectively, with `source("file.R", local=TRUE)`. This way, you can separate the app into more than just 2 files while having an "overall" view of the app through the main file, like a `main.cpp` file in C++.

Answer (score 12):

They achieve the same thing. I usually like to write my real apps, that have lots of code and are complex, as two separate files to separate the logic and make it more maintainable. But when dealing with tiny apps for demo purposes or when posting an app to Stack Overflow or anywhere else, I find it's more reproducible and easier to have one statement (the app.R) approach.

Personal preference, really.

Comment: Agreed, I had the same thoughts.

Comment: I have a app.R but it not seems to work with golbal.R file is it normal ?

Comment: As I understood for deploying on server I can go only with this option right ?   ( server.R + ui.R )
https://docs.rstudio.com/shiny-server/#local-app-configurations
`
/srv/shiny-server
-shinyApp1
---server.R
--ui.R
`

Comment: @Andrew That's incorrect, you can use both methods on shiny server or in any deploying environment

Comment: Yes, I can confirm  now.